# Domain model angular 2

Tags: json, class, angular, model

I'm receiving a json object with this form :

```
[{ 
"id": 1,
"url": "url 1",
"name": "Luke Skywalker",
"height": 172,"weight": 77,
"Cars":["car1","car2"]
}]
```

I created a data model

```
**Person.ts**
id: number;
url: string;
name: string;
height: number;
weight: number;
cars:Car[];

Car.ts:
id_car:number;
name_car:string;
info_car:string;
```

But it's not accepted to add this line (cars:Car[ ]) in the person.ts

So  how can i proceed ????

Comment: what is the error you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this :
**Person.ts**

```
    id: number;
    url: string;
    name: string;
    height: number;
    weight: number;
    cars: {
     type: [{
        type: String,
            }],

    }
```